# FME Server API - Retrieve Output file as a URL

Tags: javascript, fme-form, google-maps-api, fme-flow

I have a FME Server web workspace converting a file from SHP to KML, once it runs it outputs a kml file, I need to be able to take this file and drop into my web API google Map. Is there a way to retrieve this temporary file and display in my web map?

Comment: Yes with Data Streaming  the KML - See 'Stream KML Google Maps' http://fmeserver.com/userweb/sharper/playground/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes with Data Streaming the KML - See **'Stream KML Google Maps'**

```
[fmeserver.com/userweb/sharper/playground/index.html]

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://fmeserver.com:80/fmedatastreaming/Samples/austinApartments.fmw?');
```

is doing the request on the page request (on first load or refresh)

FME Server is running the workspace and delivering the KML back to the map and the KML is drawn on top of the Google Map.

Credit for Stewart Harper of SafeSoftware.com for creating the interactive examples.

Comment: I have seen these examples, however it doesn't seem to work. Has anyone had any luck 'reloading' the file? I am using an example on the new playground site to load on a button. http://playground.fmeserver.com/code-samples/data-streaming/google-map-layers

Comment: What does not work? I have this running on our FME Server and the example is working.

Comment: I don't know if it is my network security, as it should be working. One thing I was wondering was the http://playground.fmeserver.com/getting-started/security this says it does not work for IE (basic authentication) so what it the alternative (not REST!). If I use the playground streaming service URL it works fine, my code is the same but the server path if different.

Comment: Sounds like a firewall setting blocking your request response.

Comment: test this 'http://fmeserver.com/fmedatastreaming/Samples/austinApartments.fmw?&output=kml' you should get a response in KML format then replace 'fmeserver.com' with your IP/DNS hostname. Port 80 should be open.

Comment: I think our firewall is blocking the request, I get an X upon loading the file but doesn't display anything. Thanks anyways for all your time and help!

Comment: If I use this: http://fmeserver.com:80/fmedatastreaming/Samples/austinApartments.fmw? it works fine. Just not with our server.